# How can I list only folders with no sub folders in given path?

Tags: command-line, directory, find

Problem:I have given dir structure

```
├── kat11
│   ├── kat21
│   │   └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
│   └── kat22
│       ├── kat31
│       │   └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
│       └── kat32
│           └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
├── kat12
│   └── kat21
│       └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
├── kat13
│   └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
└── kat14
    └── Kat21
        └── Kat32
            └── Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
```

I want to list only all the child folders with full path.

eg

```
1. /kat14/kat21/kat32/Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
2. /kat11/kat22/kat31/Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
3. /kat11/kat22/kat32/Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
4. /kat12/kat21/Dokument\ bez\ nazwy
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574403/list-all-leaf-subdirectories-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `find` should be enough:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -empty
```

For example:

```
$ tree foo
foo
├── 1
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
├── 2
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── 3
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    └── 3

12 directories, 0 files
$ find foo -type d -empty
foo/2/2
foo/2/3
foo/2/1
foo/3/2
foo/3/3
foo/3/1
foo/1/2
foo/1/3
foo/1/1
$ touch foo/1/1/a foo/2/1/a foo/3/1/a 
$ find foo -type d -empty            
foo/2/2
foo/2/3
foo/3/2
foo/3/3
foo/1/2
foo/1/3
```

---

If these directories can contain files, then this would be better, but expensive:

```
find foo -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$0" -mindepth 1 -type d -printf z | grep -q z || printf "%s\n" "$0"' {} \;
```

---

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4269862/2072269) has a rather neat solution:

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -links 2
```

Since a directory without subdirectories only has two hard links, one two its parent and one to itself.

The question, phrased differently, has been asked before on Stack Overflow, Super User and Unix & Linux:

- [Use GNU find to show only the leaf directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4269798/2072269)
- [List all leaf subdirectories in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574403/2072269)
- [Using “find” to list only directories with no more childs](https://superuser.com/q/195879/334516)
- [find all end subdirectories in a tree](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86394/70524)

Comment: On the same directory as I tested it before, it gives me one empty directory, while there are 7 (that is, with no subdirs), does find make a difference in files/folders?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Your output is weird. It counts a directory with empty subdirectories as empty. O.o

Comment: no it doesn't, it counts folders *with no subfolders* as empty, which was the question.

Comment: Then why is `nonotifs-0.5.3` the first line of your output? It clearly has subfolders in it.

Comment: Note that "empty" is not what the question asked for, there can be files in the folder. The command only returns folders with no content *at all*.

Answer (score 6):

In a small python script:

```py
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

src = sys.argv[1]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for dr in dirs:
        directory = root+"/"+dr
        if len([sub for sub in os.listdir(directory) \
                if os.path.isdir(directory+"/"+sub)]) == 0:
            print(directory)
```

#### To use it

- Copy it into an empty file, save it as `count_empty.py`
- Run it with the targeted directory as an argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/count_empty.py '<source_directory>'
  ```

#### How it works

- `python`'s `os.walk()` walks through directories and sub- directories
- The line

  ```
  if len([sub for sub in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isdir(directory+"/"+sub)]) == 0:
  ```

  subsequently counts the number of *subdirectories* on each of them. If it is zero (no subdirectories), the directory and its path is printed.

Test on a simple package folder on my desktop:

```bsh
$ '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/pscript_5.py' '/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3' 
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3/nonotifs-0.5.3/manpages
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3/nonotifs-0.5.3/miscellaneous
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3/nonotifs-0.5.3/icon
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3/nonotifs-0.5.3/code
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/0.5.3/nonotifs-0.5.3/debian/source
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

This solution only works on non-btrfs filesystems:

```
find . -type d -links 2
```

The solution using *find* that works on btrfs is very complicated:

```
find . -type d \
    \( -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | grep -cz "^" >/dev/null 2>&1' _ {} \; -o -print \)
```

There's an alternative to *find* called *rawhide* (*rh*) that makes this much easier:

```
rh 'd && "[ $(rh -red -- %S | wc -l) = 0 ]".sh'
```

A slightly shorter/faster version is:

```
rh 'd && "[ -z \"$(rh -red -- %S)\" ]".sh'
```

The above commands search for directories and then list their sub-directories and only match when there are none (the first by counting the number of lines of output, and the second by checking if there is any output at all per directory).

If you don't need support for btrfs, it's more like *find* but still shorter:

```
rh 'd && nlink == 2'
```

For a version that works on all filesystems as efficiently as possible:

```
rh 'd && (nlink == 2 || nlink == 1 && "[ -z \"$(rh -red -- %S)\" ]".sh)'
```

On normal (non-btrfs) filesystems, this will work without the need for any additional processes for each directory, but on btrfs, it will need them. This is probably best if you have a mix of different filesystems including btrfs.